# React native firebase multiple notification triggered in background in one event

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

**The background notification is triggered two times in one event, which should not happen,
I am unable to detect the issue? I am using react native firebase with notifee for notification..!
This is the useEffect code, where i unsubscribe the foreground notification listener.**

```
useEffect(() => {
    networkCall()
    fetchingUserData().then(() => {
        setIsLoading(false)
    })

    //
    // This is a function for receiving the notification message and displaying notification
    //
    async function onMessageReceivedFore(message: any) {
        onDisplayNotification(message);
        console.log('message received Foreground');
    }
    async function onMessageReceivedBack(message: any) {
        onDisplayNotification(message);
        console.log('message received Background');
    }
    //
    //This is for receiving notification onForeground
    //
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceivedFore);
    //
    //This is for receiving notification on background
    //
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(onMessageReceivedBack);

    return () => {
        console.log('component unmount');
        onNotificationInteraction()
        unsubscribe()
    }

}, [])
```

Comment: you get two notification when fire from firebase?

Comment: From firebase i get one, but its something in my code i guess, which leads to displaying two notifications, its something of the listener i guess

Comment: Open your AndroidManifest file and tell me the value of `com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground` meta data

Comment: I dont have such tag in the manifest

Comment: which library you are using for push notification?

Comment: react-native-firebase, with notifee

Comment: I guess the issue is solved, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was using both onForeground() notification and onBackground() notification,
when I removed the onBackground() notification then , the onForeground method was also triggered in the background so, I was receiving two notifications in one event... This shouldn't be the case but, seems to work now...**

```
useEffect(() => {
    networkCall()
    fetchingUserData().then(() => {
        setIsLoading(false)
    })

    //
    // This is a function for receiving the notification message and displaying notification
    //
    async function onMessageReceivedFore(message: any) {
        onDisplayNotification(message);
        console.log('message received Foreground');
    }
    //
    //This is for receiving notification onForeground
    //
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceivedFore);

    return () => {
        console.log('component unmount');
        onNotificationInteraction()
        unsubscribe()
    }

}, [])
```

Comment: The issue has no gone. In foreground you calling notifee, in background you calling notifee but react-native-firebase also fires for some reason. You removed calling of notifee in background but react-native-firebase still keeps calling. It is most probably not desired behavior. Desired behavior is to handle all notification will notifee.